# Cohen's kappa with three categories of variable

Tags: cohens-kappa

I have to calculate the inter-agreement rate using cohen's kappa. However, I only know how to do it with two observers and two categories of my variable.

My task now is this:

I have a set of tweets. Each tweet should be rated as positive/negative/neutral by two observers, thus I have two observers yet 3 categories.

How should the formula of this look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find [this document](http://psych.unl.edu/psycrs/handcomp/hckappa.PDF) taken from this [refresher on Bivariate Statistics Hand-Computation Cache](http://psych.unl.edu/psycrs/handcomp/) from the University of Nebraska–Lincoln to be clear:

[image]

[image]

[image]